# Load a PDF file into a Text Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know that only real programmers can solve this problem.. I want to load a PDF file into a Text Box, I found working [`demo here`](http://checkpointcams.com/test/test.html) [`view-source:http://checkpointcams.com/test/test.html`] .... when I download HTML + JS files, and I put all files in my server and when I remove `<base href="`, and `<select>` elements, it doesn't work in my project - domain.

Can someone modify demo HTML and .js files to make this HTML run on all domains /offline mode, without that `<base href=` and `<select>` elements? Btw I think this problem is related to a file called "script19.min.js" which needs to be modified.

All that I need is, this simple working Html file + [ js files], Text Box and Upload / Load button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**
I'm unsure what your console errors are reporting, but I was able to get the pdf working on an expressjs server by placing test.html in the root of a static file server `public` and each of those minified js files in a directory named js with `public`.

```
<root_directory>/fire/public
├── js
|  ├── jquery-3.1.1.min.js
|  ├── pdf.min.js
|  ├── pdf.worker.min.js
|  ├── pdfparser2.min.js
|  └── script19.min.js
└── test
   └── test.html
```

I also made the `src`s reference relative directories in the `test.html`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/pdf.min.js"></script>
<base href="/test/">
</head>
<body>
  <br>
  <br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg tts-btn" title="Upload text, pdf or ebook file">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open-file btn-glyph" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]">
    </button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="buttons_row">
      <select class="btn btn-template-primary" id="select_language">
        <option value=" UK English Male">UK English (default)</option>
      </select>
      <select class="btn btn-template-primary" id="select_speed">
        <option value="0.9">Normal Speed</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>            
    <textarea id="text_box" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea>
    <script src="/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/pdf.worker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/pdfparser2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/script19.min.js"></script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

On my end, I did notice that the `pdf.min.js` expects a served directory named `js` so I suspect this code was built with webpack. I highly recommend diving into modern web tooling - node, npm, webpack, etc - as copy and pasting minified javascript gets hairy quickly.

**Code**

https://github.com/onescriptkid/stackoverflow60162806

**Example**

https://i.gyazo.com/64c3769f824a793cdb38d058c5e030a4.gif

Comment: thanks for the help, but it doesn't work ,as I have mentioned ,i need file without <select> elements [i need only text box and load button],when i remove them it dosent work ,I think this problem is related to a file called "script19.min.js" which needs to be modified or to be removed,but when i remove script19.min.js and elements ,i have same result it dosent work.

Comment: Since those dom elements are expected, would it be simpler to instead add a `style="display: none"` to the elements you want to hide? **Example** - `<select style="display: none" />`